# Camera advice for getting into photography 

Tags: equipment-recommendation, canon, nikon, low-light

I want to get into photography; I have been playing with the manual settings on my Canon point and shoot for a few months for various scene types and low light.

A year ago I purchased a Nikon D90, but regretfully lost my job soon after and gave it back due to finances.  Now things have stabilized and I want to get back on the horse.  I know the d90 is a great camera but it is kind of old and there have been many new comers to the DSLR game since then. I love the way the D90 felt, as opposed to lower end DSLR cameras that felt like plastic toys.

Should I get something now or wait to get the D90 successor when it comes out?  Does anyone know when that will be?

I’m only really interested in either a Nikon or Cannon, no other make please.

The type of shooting I want to focus on is low light, controlled depth of field, portraits, and family/kids... that move fast so burst mode and sport mode is needed here.

My budget is in the region of $1,000 to $1,500.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm curious where the "no other make please" requirement comes from.

Comment: Also I want to add that burst mode is not the best way to get pictures of fast-moving children. You can get lucky that way, but after practicing you'll do better being more engaged and taking one or two shots at the right moment.

Comment: @mattdm i just want to stay with one of the 2 front runnersd in dslr arena. im sure sony and pentax are great but if i need service or parts or lenses, there is a larger aftermarket for these.

Comment: You *do* need service and parts or lenses, and for that reason all of the major brands are pretty okay in those areas. It is an advantage of the biggest two, but it really should just be one factor to consider, not an initial limiter. (That said, the fact that you were happy with your D90 is a *great* reason to tend towards Nikon.)

Comment: @mattdm & @kacalapy  I'll mention something that got me banned from the Olympus Flickr forums:  There just _is_ more support, forums, 1st party gear, 3rd party gear, other people around, software, info, product research, $$$$ going into, etc around for Canon & Nikon.  The only reason(s) to go Sony, Oly etc are a) you know somebody close who also has it and you want to use them as a resource b) you have some old oly, zeiss etc lenses you want to try and c) you get _more gear_ for your money.  Overall, going Nikon or Canon is a sound decision unless you have good reason not to.

Comment: It becomes a self-fulfilling prophesy, of course. You're right that there's nothing *wrong* with going with the big two: they're big because they're good. But the fact is it's not so dire to be invested in a second-tier brand, and if you're "getting into photography", it's a mistake to *start* by limiting yourself in this way.

Comment: I tend to agree with Matt. I wouldn't be looking Sony, there are elements of the system that are too proprietary (e.g. the flash shoe), but others in the second tier such as Pentax and Olympus are not wastelands for 3rd party sources or direct repair/support. Either way, MainMa has made the suggestion I would make for somebody who is looking for a D90 improvement and likes the Nikon ergonomics.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A D90 already exists: it's Nikon D7000.

- Burst mode is up to 6 shoots per second.
- 39 points auto-focus is also much better than in D90.
- Noise seems to be better than on a D90 when shooting at higher ISO, but you have to look at different reviews to compare both and find what to expect.

The problem is that it costs approx. $1 100 - $1 200. You can buy it with a 18-105mm kit lens, but the lens quality is quite low. A 18-200mm VR2 is much better for D7000, but this lens is about $700.

My recommendation is to get a better lens with a cheaper body; so maybe a used D90 with a better lens is a way to go.

Comment: so my best bet is a d7000 body and seperate lens? what would be a realy good allaround lense to start with since the kit lense is poor choice... like headphones you get with any portable stereo... they dont bundle the goos stuff.

Comment: The 18-200 is jack of all trades, master of none.  If you're learning photography, you are probably interested in learning composition and focal isolation, both of which will be lacking with an all-in-one zoom like the 18-200.  Other zooms will serve you well, take a look at bythom.com or http://www.naturfotograf.com/ for thorough reviews of Nikon lenses across a wide range of applications.

Comment: ok i made up my mind and can not wait !!!! to get the d7000 !!!

Comment: +1 - If you aren't going to look at Pentax, then the D7000 would be my advice. The D7000 and K-5 sport the best APS-C sensor on the market right now, IMHO (as well as that of DxO and DP Review). The only funny thing is, you'll still be paying Sony as it is they who make the sensor!

Comment: hit enter to soon, i am now stuck trying to decide/ decifer my lens choices for the d7000.  i am not thrilled witht he kit lens and am looking alternatives. any ideas a lens for depth of field control, portraits, family, pets, and events.

Comment: @kacalapy - Never skimp on lenses, they affect your photography much more than the camera! For a first Nikon lens, I'd go with the AF-S DX 17-55mm F/2.8G because I like wide-angle photography, you can consider the AF-S 24-120 F/4G  instead if you prefer something longer and with a larger range, you will be able to add a wide-angle or ultra-wide lens later. Some people start with a prime lens instead but it's not for everything, as it requires more effort to compose. A 35mm is more or less standard on the D7000, but you can get a 60mm macro if you prefer.

Comment: @Itai - Sigma sells a nice 17-50 EX OS HSM F/2.8 that I think is about half the price of the official Nikon.

Comment: @rfusca - Well, I have not tried that one, so it may be an exception to the rule but my experience is that price is quite proportional to quality. Sigma's excellent lenses tend to cost similarly to those of other brands. When they cost less, they tend to perform less well too.